# ExclusiveStartKey in dynamodb paginations

Tags: java, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

i am using pagination with querySpec.withExclusiveKeyStart() as i need to give 
last Evaluated Key that is given below

```
 {bracket={N: 5895,}, logid={N: 5895,}, userid={N: 5895,}, eventiduserid={S: 1-186592,}}
```

I don't know how to pass this value to Exclusive Start Key in java where my other code is

```
querySpec.withKeyConditionExpression("eventiduserid  = :v_eventid ")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":v_eventid", "1-186592"))
                .withProjectionExpression("logid, eventid, userid, lastupdated, userurl,useraction, bracket, phasenumber, userlocation, userip, client")
                .withScanIndexForward(false)
                .withExclusiveStartKey(result.getLastEvaluatedKey());
```

Here in the place of result.getLastEvaluatedKey i want to put this value

```
 {bracket={N: 5895,}, logid={N: 5895,}, userid={N: 5895,}, eventiduserid={S: 1-186592,}}
```

but i don't know how to do it . i am deadly stuck in it and don't know how to solve this problem.